# percentage calculation for each row in hive

Tags: hive, percentage

i have got a table in hive with the following schema 
(diference int,count_value int) 
The values are
5   2,
30  1,
90  1,
100 1

Now i want to find percentage of each count_value with sum of count_value. Something like count_value/sum(count_value) for each row. Can anybody please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

With the new analytics and windowing functions introduced in Hive 0.11, you can do:

```
SELECT count_value / sum(count_value) over () as p from myTable
```

This avoids a join, plus easier to do the calculation if partitioned by another field. For example, if the source table had a `key` field and you wanted the calculation to use the sum from the rows with the same `key`, you could do:

```
SELECT count_value / sum(count_value) over (partition by key) as p from myTable
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using a subquery to calculate the total first, then joining the total to each row?

```
SELECT
    count_value / count_value_sum AS p
FROM
    myTable t
JOIN
    (SELECT SUM(count_value) AS count_value_sum FROM myTable) s
```

Hope that helps.